# text editor in uitextview

Tags: iphone

I need to build an editor where user can edit any part of the text. I mean he can bold, underline or change the fonts of any part of text. I know it is not possible to do it in UITextView, but is there any alternative to achieve this?

Answer (score 4):

See this [Apple sample](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#samplecode/CoreTextPageViewer/Introduction/Intro.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/DTS40010699) here called CoreTextPageViewer, and note that a WWDC 2010 video is available on iTunes for developers, called "Advanced Text Handling for Iphone OS".

Also, you might want to also look at [this sample code](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#samplecode/SimpleTextInput/Introduction/Intro.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/DTS40010633) from Apple.

Answer (score 1):

Why not try [CoreText](http://www.cocoanetics.com/2011/01/befriending-core-text/) !

Answer (score 1):

**UIWebView** only allow you just display the Rich content means you can not edit.

Check [this](http://www.cocoanetics.com/2011/01/rich-text-editing-on-ios/) will be useful for you

Answer (score 0):

How about using a `UIWebView` and embedding an HTML editor?

Comment: u mean I have to make a web page with html editor and display it in a webview?

Answer (score 0):

hi pankaj 
It is very much possible with text view . you have to make your own editor

Answer (score 0):

There are two common ways how people are doing rich text editing on iOS right now:

1. UIWebView plus JavaScript
2. Custom View implementing UITextInput for input and CoreText for rendering

But both are quite involved. Unfortunately Apple seems to have left out selection mechanics from UITextInput, so you would have to program all of this yourself.

Answer (score 0):

On iOS 6, [UITextView](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#DOCUMENTATION/UIKit/Reference/UITextView_Class/Reference/UITextView.html#//apple_ref/doc/c_ref/UITextView) now supports rich text.
Look at the [attributedText](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/DOCUMENTATION/UIKit/Reference/UITextView_Class/Reference/UITextView.html#//apple_ref/occ/instp/UITextView/attributedText) property:

```
@property(nonatomic,copy) NSAttributedString *attributedText
```